# NestJS can't resolve dependecies of the LocalAuthGuard

Tags: nestjs, backend

I'm following NestJS docs on the authentication topic, but for some reason the program doesn't work. I'm literally copying and pasting all the code, and doing all the CLI commands, but it keeps giving me this error:

```
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the LocalAuthGuard. Please make sure that the "optios available in the current context.

Potential solutions:
- If AuthModuleOptions is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
- If AuthModuleOptions is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within App
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing AuthModuleOptions */ ]
  })
```

AuthModuleOptions isn't anywhere in the code, so what could it be? I Honestly have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

[There's a bug that was published in 8.1.1](https://github.com/nestjs/passport/issues/823). [There's an open PR to fix it](https://github.com/nestjs/passport/pull/824).

Comment: ah, nice, I thought what the hell I was doing wrong haha. Should I just downgrade the Nest version, or there is a way around? I'm just learning, so I don't know what I could do instead.

Comment: Like the linked issue says, you cna add `PassportModule.register({})` to every module  where you use `AuthGuard()` or you can downgrade to 8.1.0 and pin the dep